# angular modules and lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I need a bit of help with logical division of modularity and lazy loading.

I have the app for which there is an extensive administrative section. You can add/remove different pieces of data that the main application is using. While the admin section is extensive it's seldom used. It'd seem logical to have the admin section as module that is only lazy loaded if someone goes to one of the admin routes.

What I struggle with is separation of concerns. Let's say I have a list of `contacts`. There is a whole admin page where you can add/edit/delete `contacts`. There is a `contact.model.ts` and `contacts.service.ts` as well as the component used to display stuff. It seems logical that all of that would live in the module.

Now the main section needs some of that stuff too specifically `contact.model.ts` and `contacts.service.ts`. I understand that the model file is just typescript dev sugar and don't actually mean anything at runtime. The `contacts.service.ts` however is an injectable that seems like it should be exported by the `adminmodule`.

Is that the right approach? And if so - won't the `contacts.service.ts` either be unavailable at runtime cause the `adminmodule` isn't loaded OR cause the `adminmodule` to load when the service is used in `mainmodule` therefore defeating lazy loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach isn't bad, but if you want to keep the lazy loaded module as tiny and lightweight as possible, it's better to flip it around.

Anything used by the main app, or shared between modules, can be considered `shared`. When the lazy loaded module requires something from `shared`, it's already loaded as you can imagine the main app requires it as well at some point.

In your lazy loaded module for `admin`, should only be `admin` related things. You can reuse things like the model and service if another module requires them. But a specific admin service or extension to the model that only an admin would required is fine to be put into the `AdminModule`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ooo interesting I'll try that. It's not that I want the lazy loaded module to be tiny (it's so rarely loaded I don't particularly care, I'd rather the main one was tiny) it's that I don't want to dup the code. It's sounds that the way I described `contact.service.ts` would have to be in both modules right? Thanks for flipping my perspective around :)

Comment: The `contact.service.ts` could be in a `SharedContactModule` which both would import. This depends however if there is a non-shared part of a `ContactModule`. Nothing is stopping you from making a `/shared/contact/contact.module` import/exporting a `contact.service.ts` and a `contact.model.ts`

Comment: There is a 100% chance of needing the `contact.service.ts` on page 1 of the main app/module. I don't even think I need a `sharedodule` I just need to put all the shared stuff into main but put admin related components into the `adminmodule`

Comment: That's even better! Hope that helps!